# How can I get sin, cos, and tan to use degrees instead of radians?

Tags: javascript, math

When I'm working with math in JS I would like its trig functions to use degree values instead of radian values. How would I do that?

Comment: sin/cos/tan don't return angles in radians; they take angles in radians. The inverse functions `atan()`, `atan2()`, `acos()`, `asin()` return angles.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You can use a function like this to do the conversion:

```
function toDegrees (angle) {
  return angle * (180 / Math.PI);
}
```

Note that functions like `sin`, `cos`, and so on *do not return angles*, they take angles as input. It seems to me that it would be more useful to you to have a function that converts a degree input to radians, like this:

```
function toRadians (angle) {
  return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```

which you could use to do something like `tan(toRadians(45))`.

Answer (score 41):

Multiply the input by `Math.PI/180` to convert from degrees to radians before calling the system trig functions.

You could also define your own functions:

```
function sinDegrees(angleDegrees) {
    return Math.sin(angleDegrees*Math.PI/180);
};
```

and so on.

Comment: This should really be named `sinDegrees` to avoid confusion

Comment: True. I've seen some sites call is `sind` to keep it short. I personally keep it to `sin` because I know that `sin` will then be in degrees and `Math.sin` in radians, but that's on my own head.

Comment: -1: sin() doesn't return an angle. Its input argument is an angle.

Comment: That... that one got away from me. I know that. Of course I know that. I wouldn't have made a bazillion games with trig functions if I hadn't... but for some reason I kinda completely forgot that =/

Comment: I'm a noob and bad with trig...may I ask how the equation for cosDeg and tanDeg would look like? thank you.

Comment: @Kama Exactly the same, but with `sin` and `tan` inside.

Comment: I tried to get the cosine of 90 using Math.cos(90/180*Math.PI). the answer is 6.123233995736766e-17. When it should be 0 more or less.

Comment: The `e-17` tells you that it's `0.00000000000000006123...`

Answer (score 14):

I created my own little lazy Math-Object for degree (MathD), hope it helps:

```
//helper
/**
 * converts degree to radians
 * @param degree
 * @returns {number}
 */
var toRadians = function (degree) {
    return degree * (Math.PI / 180);
};

/**
 * Converts radian to degree
 * @param radians
 * @returns {number}
 */
var toDegree = function (radians) {
    return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
}

/**
 * Rounds a number mathematical correct to the number of decimals
 * @param number
 * @param decimals (optional, default: 5)
 * @returns {number}
 */
var roundNumber = function(number, decimals) {
    decimals = decimals || 5;
    return Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
}
//the object
var MathD = {
    sin: function(number){
        return roundNumber(Math.sin(toRadians(number)));
    },
    cos: function(number){
        return roundNumber(Math.cos(toRadians(number)));
    },
    tan: function(number){
        return roundNumber(Math.tan(toRadians(number)));
    },
    asin: function(number){
        return roundNumber(toDegree(Math.asin(number)));
    },
    acos: function(number){
       return roundNumber(toDegree(Math.acos(number)));
   },
   atan: function(number){
       return roundNumber(toDegree(Math.atan(number)));
   }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

I like a more general functional approach:

```
/**
* converts a trig function taking radians to degrees
* @param {function} trigFunc - eg. Math.cos, Math.sin, etc.
* @param {number} angle - in degrees
* @returns {number}
*/
const dTrig = (trigFunc, angle) => trigFunc(angle * Math.PI / 180);
```

or,

```
function dTrig(trigFunc, angle) {
  return trigFunc(angle * Math.PI / 180);
}
```

which can be used with any radian-taking function:

```
dTrig(Math.sin, 90);
  // -> 1

dTrig(Math.tan, 180);
  // -> 0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's not especially functional or general. What if it takes two arguments? What if it returns something in radians (`Math.asin()` for example) and you want to get degrees as output? The accepted answer is using just the right amount of functional programming. An unnecessary use of a function as an argument doesn't make it a functional programming approach.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [project with more than a thousand stars on GitHub](https://github.com/stdlib-js/stdlib) that provides functions for converting from degrees to radians and radians to degrees.

To install:

```
npm i @stdlib/math
```

To import:

```js
const rad2deg = require('@stdlib/math/base/special/rad2deg')
const deg2rad require('@stdlib/math/base/special/deg2rad')
```

To use:

```js
console.log(Math.sin(deg2rad(90)))
console.log(rad2deg(Math.asin(1)))
```