# Convert complex excel formula to javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

To start I'm not that well versed in javascript and I'm trying to convert this complex excel formula to javascript without any luck.

```
=DEGREES(ASIN(SIN(RADIANS(59.036))*SIN(RADIANS(150))))/2
```

Here's what I have so far

```
var x = DEGREES(Math.asin(Math.sin(RADIANS(59.036))*Math.sin(RADIANS(150))))/2
```

Obviously, `DEGREES` and `RADIANS` are wrong and I can't figure what the javascript equivalent would be.

(BTW the correct answer is 5.831)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705123/how-can-i-get-sin-cos-and-tan-to-return-degrees-instead-of-radians).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could write your own `DEGREES` and `RADIANS` functions, which only involve a little math:

```
function degrees(x) { return x * 180 / Math.PI; }
function radians(x) { return x * Math.PI / 180; }

var x = degrees(Math.asin(Math.sin(radians(59.036))*Math.sin(radians(150))))/2;
```

Comment: @SethBattin Yours as well.

Comment: Boy, that was simple.  I was playing with this for an hour. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define both functions yourself.  They are both trivial to implement.

```
function DEGREES(radians){
  return (radians * 180 / Math.PI);
}
function RADIANS(degrees){
  return (degrees / 180 * Math.PI);
}
```